# Запись в две базы параллельно YII2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Например у меня есть база Article и у нее есть связь с таблицей youtube, как сделать чтобы при создании/редактировании article можно было добавлять/ удалять/изменять youtube

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Дополните пожалуйста. Как может быть связь базы с таблицей??

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Ну например у меня таблица article и в ней id | title | text, далее я хочу связать таблицу youtube айдишником, то есть - id | name | article_id. Связь будет по article_id

Comment: ну так а что вам мешает это делать? просто есть одно условия. Чтобы id подтянутой таблицы всегда существовал, иначе ошибка будет. Т е вы сначала создаете в табл `yuotube` новую запись с `id` =  `2`, а потом вы создаете запись в таблице `article` и можете использовать  `id = 2` с таблици `youtube`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Дело в том что это нужно сделать моделями в yii2

Comment: И в чем проблема...делаете модели для двух таблиц через gii и в экшене используете две можели